# stylesheet not working online but offline

Tags: css, stylesheet

This website http://gem19.ir/ seems not loading stylesheet. When I save it locally, everything works fine.

I have checked there is no bug or error reported in console. Is there any syntax error or other serverside reason?

this is the line that css is imported:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/farsi/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" />
```

Comment: Could you post your html code where the links are defined? The problem is likely to be there.

Comment: I added the css line to my question. Did you mean this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server isn't setting the MIME types correctly. The console reported notices of this later.

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XWDc.png)
[image: Resource Interpreted as X but transferred with MIME type Y]

Make a .htaccess file on your webserver if it doesn't exist yet and add the following:

```
AddType text/css .css
AddType application/javascript .js
```

If that doesn't do the trick, then your webserver still has something wrong in its configuration, which would be why it is transferring the MIME types.

Comment: Thank you. Where did you get this report?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour In my Chrome's  Developer Console. You're welcome!